# Error executing grumphp: hit windows cmd input limit

Tags: php, testing, backend

When I run the task phpmd inside of grumphp, using the comand:

```
./vendor/bin/grumphp run --tasks phpmd
```

I get the following error:

> Running task 1/1: phpmd...
>   Oh no, we hit the windows cmd input limit!
>   Skipping task...

I have read in multiple publications which say that I must increase the `cmd input limit`, But I could not find an implementation that works for me.

I am using Windows PowerShell as console and I have windows 10, I appreciate any suggestion.